# Arduino Nano with water pump - stop pump from running when booting

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino Nano running a pump. The pump runs 2 seconds (via a relay) when a soil moisture sensor reaches a threshold.

My problem is that when the Nano boots it runs the pump for the 2 seconds. Is there any way I can avoid this?

[This is the schematics](https://github.com/pkold/Self-watering-plant-system/blob/master/schematics_bb.pdf)

[This is the code running on the Nano](https://github.com/pkold/Self-watering-plant-system/blob/master/Arduino%20Python%20code/code.ino)

[The Github repo](https://github.com/pkold/Self-watering-plant-system)

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: See the How to Ask page :)

Comment: I have added the code and schematics.

Comment: @datafiddler Just to be sure. Are you saying "See the How to ask page" because of the missing code? I am pretty new here and want to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can avoid this?

Yes.

If you show how you do it (sketch and circuit), someone can show you how to avoid it.

Probably you use a Low-Active relay module not in the best way.
Easiest don't use a pin set to OUTPUT, while the bootloader is waiting on Serial.

Comment: If this question is the same as the one here : https://github.com/pkold/Self-watering-plant-system/blob/master/Arduino%20Python%20code/code.ino  your problem is not the time while in bootloader but your error in setup()

Comment: `digitalWrite(pump, LOW); // switch pump on`

Comment: Thank you :-) I see now! I will test later. :-)